# Rhino Mocks: Minimal times to call seems not to work

Tags: unit-testing, tdd, mocking, rhino-mocks

Im using Rhino-Mocks 3.6 as mocking framework in my unit tests and have a problem with `Repeat.Times()`:

I want to verify that a method on my mocked object is called exactly three times. According to the docs i should use `Repeat.Times(3)` or `Repeat.Times(3, 3)`.

But what i observe is that its verifying for *at least* three calls, so when i call the method four times, my test still passes. It fails when calling the method only two times.

Here is my code. Is there anything wrong with it?

```
        MockRepository mocks = new MockRepository();
        IJobServiceEvent mockedJSE;
        using (mocks.Record())
        {
            mockedJSE = mocks.DynamicMock<IJobServiceEvent>();
            Expect.Call(() => mockedJSE.TransactionListChanged(null))
                .Repeat.Times(3);
        }

        using (mocks.Playback())
        {
            mockedJSE.TransactionListChanged(null);
            mockedJSE.TransactionListChanged(null);
            mockedJSE.TransactionListChanged(null);
            mockedJSE.TransactionListChanged(null);
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a StrictMock.  A DynamicMock will allow methods calls that aren't expected.  So your call to your method is expected three times (which happens).  But when it happens a fourth time, it's not an error since you defined it as a DynamicMock (unexpected calls are allowed).

However, in the long run, using StrickMock can be a maintenance headache since your test knows too much about how the object is written (since you have to mock/stub every possible call that may be made).

I would recommend the AAA (Arrange, Act, Assert) syntax for your unit tests.  Your test above could be written using a Stub, but still enforce the 3-limit call on your method:

```
IJobServiceEvent mockedJSE = MockRepository.GenerateStub<IJobServiceEvent>();

mockedJSE.TransactionListChanged(null);
mockedJSE.TransactionListChanged(null);
mockedJSE.TransactionListChanged(null);
mockedJSE.TransactionListChanged(null);

mockedJSE.AssertWasCalled(s => s.TransactionListChanged(null), o => o.Repeat.Times(3, 3));
```

**UPDATE**

To make sure only calls with certain args were made (although I do think this is basically a strict mock which can become a maintenance headache), use the arg constraints option three times to make sure those calls are made.  Then have a final "AssertWasCalled" that ignores the arguments and make sure it only was called three times:

```
mockedJSE.AssertWasCalled(s => s.TransactionListChanged(null), o => o.IgnoreArguments().Repeat.Times(3, 3));
```

Comment: Ok, in addition i want to verify two calls of the same method with different parameters. I can get this to work by using Contraints() and calling AssertWasCalled twice. But how do i verify in this scenario that no third call with any other parameter combination occurs? Do i have to use a strict mock here?

Comment: See my update.  That should work for what you're looking for.